# How do I get a bitmap value from my Canvas composable in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to find a couple solutions but I couldn't find anything that worked. Is there a way for me to get the Bitmap value or even a Picture object from a given Canvas?

[This was one solution I found.](https://medium.com/@chiragthummar16/converting-composables-to-bitmap-using-canvas-525573abf70f)

The problem is that "draw" is an unresolved reference and I don't know what it's supposed to do.

```
draw(this, this.layoutDirection, pictureCanvas, this.size) {
    this@onDrawWithContent.drawContent()
}
```